# AWS and Grafana, whitelist IP’s

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana

I need to check if anyone has grafana connected to Prometheus on AWS. Grafana, has shared a list of more than 100 IP’s for us to whitelist and they cannot guarantee which IP will access our applications prometheus instance. Now for each IP whitelist we have to create an inbound rule, however as per AWS recommendation you should not go beyond 120 such rules. That means we cannot add those 100+ IP’s. Now grafana team is not able to support us, even with premium services, so checking here if someone has used grafana by whitelisting all IPs? I cannot expose the application to everyone over the internet.

Comment: Not as a suggestion, but rather as expansion of original question: have thought about moving to aws managed grafana?

Comment: I would say you can expose the application to everyone over the internet - you just need authentification. Blind guess: you can expose AWS Prometheus over API Gateway (where you can enable API key auth).